# How to make pycharm load anaconda environment variables

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I have been trying to set up a tensorflow-gpu environment for quite a while now. After fiddling around I decided to try anaconda, and it managed to install all the depencies inculding the CUDA toolkit and cuDNN, great!

However, pycharm seems not to activate the anaconda environment, and is thus missing the environment variables.

If I activate my environment in a terminal and run:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)
```

it works and returns

```
1.12.0
```

However, when I open pycharm and try the same (either in terminal or by creating a test_file.py with the same code), it throws a DLL error, which indicates it cannot find the environment variables. (The project interpreter is set to the conda environment).

I have found posts from late 2018 saying it is a known issue, but cannot find a solution anywhere. I love pycharm as an IDE and would love to be able to use it for this project, but right now it is useless. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be eternally grateful.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question

Comment: Seeing that you already set the conda interpreter, it could be an issue with tensorflow. Or you could have accidentally installed it in the wrong environment(pip?).
Try taking these steps if you haven't already:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment WhiteHat. I have done those steps, tried both using an existing and creating a new conda environment. I don't think it is an issue in TensorFlow. I have since found out that if I activate the conda environment in CMD, and then launch pycharm from that CMD, it will work. This works for now but is a bit tedious, would be great if I could find a solution where I can just launch PyCharm normally.

Comment: Try PyCharm 2019.1 EAP https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/, there is a relevant fix there: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234

Comment: Wow thanks! Both of those solved my problem. I will definitely be using the EAP now. If you post this as an answer instead of a comment I can flag it as correct for other people who might be having the same problem :)